# state vs props for scenario with separate view and data model

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an application where I would like to provide separate views for same data.

In my current implementation, data is obtained by web service call and persisted in `state` of `App` component in `App.js`. `App` component hosts (renders) another component called `StackEditor`, which acts as a view for `this.state.components` in `App` component.

UI elements rendered by `StackEditor` can be moved around, and to synchronize `state` of `App` I do it as below:

```
<StackEditor
  components={this.state.components}
  onLocationChanged={this.handleLocationChanged} />
```

In `handleLocationChanged` I update the `state`:

```
handleLocationChanged(e, data) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        // event data copied to state here
        return {components: prevState.components};
    });
}
```

As `state` is now updated, this forces `StackEditor` to be rendered again, as its property `components` is bound to `state` as `components={this.state.components}` (see in the code snippet above).

This all works, but now I started questioning if I'm doing it right.

Q1: Should I be using `state` instead of `props`?

It seems that location of component is mutated in principle, although from `StackEditor` point of view, it is immutable (I can decide that change is invalid and not to update the `state` in event listener).

Q2: Is it possible to share part of the state between 2 components in React?

If I somehow convert `StackEditor` from getting components from `state` instead of `props`, will I get notification on state changed by child component (`StackEditor`) in my parent component (`App`)?

Q3: Also, are `props` more convenient to use than `state` in general?

When I created another component following HOC guidelines (https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) I discovered that `props` are easily forwarded to "wrapped" component, but not `state`. If I provide a function to call back via property (as I did above), "wrapped" component can easily call it, without even noticing that it's "wrapped". I don't see how I can easily notify "wrapped" component about `state` change in "wrapper", without writing some extra code.

Answer (score 2):

If you imagine your application to be a tree of components in a well designed app it's usually like this:

- the **leafs** are stateless components . They decide **how data is rendered**.
- the **nodes** are stateful components. They decide **which components and data to render**.

> Q1: Should I be using state instead of props?

It depends on which category of components you have (node or leaf).

> Q2: Is it possible to share part of the state between 2 components in
>   React?

If you feel that your app has a lot of state that mutates and needs to be used by several components spread over your tree you usually start to introduce an external state management library (e.g. [`redux`](https://redux.js.org/)). Components can subscribe to your store and become stateless as your store now handles the state.

> Q3: Also, are props more convenient to use than state in general?

They solve different problems so you can't really say that. A stateless component is usually easier to understand but has no capabilities to control anything.

Also read [Identify where your state should live](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live) and [When to use redux](https://medium.com/@fastphrase/when-to-use-redux-f0aa70b5b1e2).

All that is only a rule of thumb. A lot of the time you will have components that have both `state` and `props` because they control parts of your app but delegate other parts to their children.

> This all works, but now I started questioning if I'm doing it right.

As far as I can see from the code you provided this looks pretty much as it has to.

Comment: for #2 you do not necesarily need redux to pass state between two components I dont think its good to always reccomend redux for basic react apps.  #3 a stateless component can still receive props, and handlers like onlcick and onchange so they can control things.

Comment: @Omar I agree, you do not need redux all the time. But if you want to share state between components you have to lift it up. And if you find yourself having a fair amount of state in the top level component it may be time for redux as this it is well documented and maintained. To #3: Sure, they may call a handler but what happens on a call is entirely under control of the component that implements the handler (which is usually the stateful component). They can't alter the state by themself, that is what I mean with "control".